# Using Google Map for directions on iPhones with non-english language

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps

I attempt to give my users directions to a POI using Google maps from within my app.

I open the following url and Google maps opens as expected:

```
http://maps.google.com/?saddr=Current%20Location&doflg=ptm&daddr=TEST@55.227784,9.351642
```

Directions are shown correctly as long as the language of the iPhone is set to English, but when I set it to German or Danish, no directions can be found. Do I need to encode the URL different? -or am I missing something else?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending several hours on this problem I found a solution.

it turns out that Current%20Location only works when the iPhone is set to English (I guess 'Current Location' for some strange reason is localized, so maybe one could use some language specific string here).

Instead I'm now using the user's current GPS position obtained from CoreLocation.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Few additions - it works in other languages as well if you use localized version of "current location". Unfortunately this doesn't work on iPad for some reason. More info can be found here: http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps